# Is there a way to store a variable during a while loop?

Tags: c++

I am using a do-while loop that will ask the user to input positive numbers. The program will terminate when I enter a zero (0) number. Then it will compute the sum of all numbers I have entered and display it.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main () {
    
    int end = 0;
    int num1;

        
    do {
        cout << "Enter a number:";
        cin >> num1;
        cout << "\n" << endl;

    } while (end != num1); 

    {
        cout << "sum = " << num1+num1;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are always overwriting `num1` - you need to use some container to store all inputs (e.g.: a `std::vector<int>`)

Comment: Define another variable (say `sum`) and initialise it to zero before the loop.   In the loop body (so it happens every loop iteration) add `num1` to `sum`.

Comment: add up the numbers inside the loop

Comment: For computing a sum of a list of numbers you don't need or want to store the individual numbers in some array or vector. You just add as you go.

Comment: I have fixed it and I'm still learning more. Thank you for all the ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

its a simple program. you can add code for exception in it

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  int n=0;
  int sum=0;
  do {
    cin>>n;
    sum+=n;
  }while(n); // this loop will break when n=0
  
  cout<<sum;

}
```

Comment: Thank you, I now understand. I'm still learning and I'm eager to learn more

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify some sort of `sum` variable, which you will increment each iteration by the entered number.

Possible solution:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int sum = 0;
    // '10' can be changed according to how many numbers you want to input
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        int temp;
        std::cin >> temp; 
        sum += temp;
    }
    std::cout << sum << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```